# How do I add a default text field that any new crafter component will have no matter what component type

Tags: crafter-cms

I want the ability to include a text field on any of the components my users use in crafter.  Just like Intnernal Name is automatically added to every component.  So whether I bring up component Type A or component Type B, it will automatically have this field without having to manually add it to every component.

I assume I have to modify some crafter code but not sure where?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a cross-cutting field that's in all/most components, you should consider inheritance:

https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.1/developers/content-inheritance.html